# How to pull data from aws rds postgresql using kafka locally?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-rds, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have postgresql database server on aws. I have setup one node kafka cluster on my local machine and want to pull data from postgresql database server. i have been using jdbc source connector here is the configuration(changed the actual values)

```
name=test-source-postgresql-jdbc-01
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSourceConnector
tasks.max=1
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=http://localhost:8081
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://hostname:5432/dbname? 
user=abc&password=pwd
connection.user=abc
connection.password=pwd
table.whitelist=abc1
mode=timestamp
timestamp.column.name=timestamp
topic.prefix=test-postgresql-
```

and getting following error while running

```
ERROR Failed to create job for etc/kafka-connect-jdbc/quickstart-postgresql.properties (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:102)
ERROR Stopping after connector error (org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectStandalone:113)
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.connect.runtime.rest.errors.BadRequestException: Connector 
configuration is invalid and contains the following 2 error(s):
Invalid value org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to hostname:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections. for configuration Couldn't open connection to jdbc:postgresql://abc:5432/dbname?user=abc&password=pwd
```

curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins[Please click link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EeBvR.png)

ls share/java/kafka-connect-jdbc -l [Please click link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wQk3n.png)

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You need to go further back in your worker log to see what the cause of the shutdown is. Either that's been triggered by the process being shutdown (SIGTERM, closing the console window, etc), or something's caused it to abort.

Comment: it could be SSH issue since, i connect DB clients like postico/pgAdmin/PSequel with SSH only but kafka not really sure how to configure it.

Comment: You could use GNU `screen` to keep processes running even on disconnect

Comment: I think the problem is mine connector is not running. I have added error log file in question section. please have a look.

Comment: I can't see the error log in your question, just the original log output, in which it just shows Kafka Connect is shutting down.

Comment: Yeah actually there's no logs i checked I am getting the same error like this https://github.com/confluentinc/kafka-connect-jdbc/issues/537 I have placed the jar file but connector is not running. postgresql on aws server.

Comment: @p-singh what is your `plugin.path` config property set to? Can you also post listing of that directory? When you call `curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins` is `JdbcSourceConnector` connector loaded?

Comment: @belo plugin.path=share/java, have mentioned my config file above. jdbcsourceconnector is loaded. I have added o/p of this curl localhost:8083/connector-plugins above have a look.

Comment: I don't see the output. Just the original post.

Comment: Sorry for delay i added please have a look click on the links.

Comment: hmm, it looks OK to me. So if you see the error as in the link posted above. you can check what `connect.properties` file is actually used by the running process of the kafka connect. `ps ufax | grep org.apache.kafka.connect.cli.ConnectDistributed` and then `less path/to/connect.properties` and check that `plugin.path` actually points to the directory with connectors.

Comment: if you look at the error logs it refused to connect to aws db server. may be it asked for SSH keys. can you tell me how to configure kafka connect with SSH. is it required? for kafka because i could able to access the same data by psql client using SSH only kafka have this issue.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you're connecting to RDS via SSH tunnel. I don't think you can configure Kafka JDBC connector to tunnel through SSH automatically but you can create SSH tunnel manually and then configure Kafka connector to connect to RDS through this tunnel - detail description [here](https://medium.com/@michalisantoniou6/connect-to-an-aws-rds-using-an-ssh-tunnel-22f3bd597924).

Following your configuration, you can create SSH tunnel with command

```
ssh -N -L 5432:rds.hostname:5432 uername@ec2instnace.com -i ~/.ssh/your_key
```

You can test connection to the DB using:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432
```

And your connector config would be

```
connection.url=jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname?user=abc&password=pwd
```

Comment: As you suggested i logged in using SSH, i am using confluent kafka so when i ran  getting same error. inside confluent folder i can't do that i ran on terminal this command. there's must be some process in kafka using SSH. any idea plz let me know.